# R - convert images filenames to integers

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 3 columns. One is a column with numbered filenames. Here's a subset:

```
File_Name
000000079.png
000000082.png
000000083.png
000000089.png
000000090.png
...
```

I would like to add a new integer column that simply has the number of each filename. For example:

```
File_Number
79
82 
83
89
90
...
```

Comment: Posting a question in order to answer it yourself is fine, but like with any question you should check that it hasn't already been asked. Extracting a number from a string has been pretty extensively covered

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the extract_numeric function from TidyR or readr::parse_number().

```
# First, create a character vector from the column with your filenames. 

File_Name <- df$File_Name

# Extract numbers 

library(tidyr)
df$File_Numbers <- extract_numeric(File_Name)
```

Using readr::parse_number().

```
# First, create a character vector from the column with your filenames. 

File_Name <- df$File_Name

# Extract numbers 

library(readr)
df$File_Numbers <- parse_number(File_Name)
```